# A better way to find duplicates?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

This is something that has been bugging me for a while.

It is not uncommon for the same question to be asked repeatedly.  Take this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1508377/trying-to-allow-ssh-connections-over-the-internet-to-my-pc-running-ubuntu) that was asked today.  This question, in one form or another has been asked hundreds, if not thousands of times.  Sometimes it will get marked as a duplicate, other times it wont.  Absolutely no offense to RedGrittyBrick who answered the question, but Im sure he is well aware this question has been asked countless times as he has been on the platform as long as me, but I doubt he bothered to look up a previous iteration of the question.  I dont blame him, as I have ended up answering questions, rather than marking them as duplicates since it can be *VERY* difficult to find find them.  It takes *far* less time to answer the question then to find the duplicate - assuming you can find it.  Heck, I have reanswered questions knowing I have previously answered the question, but couldnt find my own answer!

There really are a lot of duplicate questions that get reanswered repeatedly.  There has to be a better way.

One idea, off the top of my head, would be to find these super common duplicates and write a definitive post on them.  So when these common questions come in, you can point them to a well written approved post.

Thought?  Ideas?

Comment: Excellent idea. I keep my own stash of links to canonical question/answers that I frequently refer to when closing duplicates. I'll post them in an answer and folks can add any of their own favourites.

Comment: There is also a tag [community-faq](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq) which is not often used, with 36 questions.

Comment: My way is to google the question or a rephrased version, I find many super user dupes this way.

Comment: How do you usually search for duplicates? Using the search box in Super User itself (ie `[ffmpeg] scale2ref is:answer`), a site search using a search engine (`site:superuser.com scale2ref ffmpeg`), or some other method?

Comment: It feels appropriate to cross-link this to the Ask Different equivalent, which may also be useful for research, even if we can't directly close as dupe - https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/where-is-the-list-of-canonical-questions-stored-for-ask-different

Comment: Well Logan, ill tell you what id do..

Answer (score 14):

#### List of Canonical Questions/Answers that can be used as Duplicate Targets

[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)?

[How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

[What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

[What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

[How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer)

[How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

[USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size](https://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem)

[What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)

[How do I troubleshoot a Windows freeze or slowness?](https://superuser.com/questions/26862/how-do-i-troubleshoot-a-windows-freeze-or-slowness)

[How can I tell what RAM will fit my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/18995/how-can-i-tell-what-ram-will-fit-my-computer)

[How do I identify hardware I am unfamiliar with on my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/709913/how-do-i-identify-hardware-i-am-unfamiliar-with-on-my-computer)

[Merging two incoming broadband lines for faster Internet](https://superuser.com/questions/660798/merging-two-incoming-broadband-lines-for-faster-internet)

---

#### List of Canonical Questions/Answers on other Sites that can be pointed out to Users

[What are the different widely used RAID levels and when should I consider them?](https://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them)

[How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work)

[Where is the list of canonical questions stored for Ask Different?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/where-is-the-list-of-canonical-questions-stored-for-ask-different)